# Inserting the element-wise mean of nested list into the same list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Suppose there is a list of nested lists of floats

```
L = [[a,b,c],[e,f,g],[h,i,j]]
```

What kind of function can I define to iterate through the list once and insert the mean of elements of every consecutive list into the same list? I.e. I want to get

```
L1 = [[a,b,c],[(a+e)/2,(b+f)/2,(c+g)/2],[e,f,g],[(e+h)/2,(f+i)/2,(g+j)/2],[h,i,j]]
```

I know the function to get the element wise mean of two lists:

```
from operator import add
new_list = list(map(add,list1,list2))
J = [j/2 for j in new_list]
```

However inserting this list of mean values back into the same list while maintaining the proper index iteration through the old list proved challenging.

Comment: Just construct a new list, and mutate back into the original list if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases:

1. You don't care if the resulting list is the same list:

```
new_list = []
for i in range(len(L)-1):
    new_list.append(L[i])
    new_list.append(list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x), zip(L[i],L[i+1]))))
new_list.append(L[-1])
```

2. You want the changes to be done in-place:

```
i=0
while i < len(L)-1:
    new_elem = list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x), zip(L[i],L[i+1])))
    L.insert(i+1, new_elem)
    i += 2
```

EDIT: If you're using python 3.4 or above, instead of `lambda x: sum(x)/len(x)` you can use `mean(x)` (from the package `statistics`).

Comment: thank you, for number 2 there is a small typo: i < len(L) - 1

Comment: avoid using `lambda` and just use the builtin `mean` from the stdlib in the `statistics` library